# App name is free but heroku apps:create says it is taken. How to get a name?

Tags: heroku

When I type:

```
heroku apps:create myapp
```

I get an answer:

```
 !    Name is already taken
```

When I go to the url `http://myapp.herokuapp.com/` it says that Heroku doesn't have such an app:

[image]

Is this some bug? How may I take the name?

**UPD**

Of course "myapp" is for an example name here. Of course I provide different name to Heroku when I try to register. And for that different name I get such a response.

Comment: It might be a reserved name (that is, a name they don't allow you to use because it could cause confusion).

Comment: Not a good design decision

Comment: What name are you trying to use? There're good reasons to now allow people to use names like "admin", "example", "heroku", and the like (or "myapp", if you're really trying to use that name).

Comment: I don't think Heroku has 'reserved names'. Do you have a link? I'd be interested to know if they do.

Comment: Have you tried to create the app through their UI ?

Answer (score 4):

This error message means that somebody - ANYBODY - has already taken that app name.
In this example "myapp" has already been taken.
Try adding some additional letters to "myapp" such as "myapp-this-name-has-not-been-taken-yet"

Keep trying different names until the error message goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt `myapp` is a reserved name.

Someone has created an app using `myapp`, but have **not deployed** anything, which is why you get the 'No such app' error message.

Comment: I don't think so. That's an app with nothing deployed on it: http://hidden-caverns-8064.herokuapp.com/ and that's an app which (probably) doesn't exist: http://edezde.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please change your application name because of you are given name is already taken by other users.

Answer (score -1):

myapp is a reserved name.  In the future you can type:
    `heroku apps`
from the command line
to see what apps you have registered.